# Apache Tika Server Failed to receive startup confirmation from startServer

Tags: python, pdf, apache-tika, text-extraction

I am trying to use Tika in python to extract text from the pdf files. I have Java 8 installed on my system. Despite that, I am unable to convert these pdf's into text file. Below is the code that I am using:

```
    file_name = file.split('\\')[-1]
    path = "C:/Users/user_name/PDF_Files/"+file_name
    raw = parser.from_file(path)
    name = path.split('/')[-1][:-4]
    print(name)
    file_name = "C:/Users/user_name/PDF_Files/"+name+".txt"
    text_file = open(file_name,"w",encoding="utf-8")
    if raw['content'] is not None:
        text_file = open(file_name,"w",encoding="utf-8")
        text_file.write(raw['content'])
        text_file.close()

 for file in glob.glob("C:/Users/user_name/PDF_Files/*.pdf"):
    gettext(file)
```

Below is the error message that I am getting after running the above code:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voRZO.png)

2019-11-07 15:09:06,062 [MainThread  ] [ERROR]  Unable to run java; is it installed?
2019-11-07 15:09:06,062 [MainThread  ] [ERROR]  Failed to receive startup confirmation from startServer.

Comment: Is Java on your path? Does running `java -version` from the command line work?

Comment: @Gagravarr running java -version on cmd prompt returns the message: 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Right, you'll need to fix that then! Add Java to your `PATH`, then try Tika again only once you can run java without problems

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, After some trial, I resolved the issue as

**For ubuntu,In the terminal**

```
java --version
```

1.Path not correct -> configure it.

2.Old java version -> update it.

**3. Java not available -> install it**

I followed below for installation

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install default-jdk # Confirm the installation by typing y (yes) and press Enter.
sudo apt update
sudo apt install default-jre
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java11-installer
```

**Finally check again,**

```
java --version
```

Now head on to check tika again!!